# Parametrized hexadecimal literal in DB2 C# IBM driver

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, db2, prepared-statement

There is DB2 database.

There is C#.NET application, which uses IBM.Data.DB2 driver to connect to the database (IBMDB2).

There is a parametrized query (DB2Command object, initialized with):

`"SELECT $coid_ref FROM db.$ext WHERE $coid = @coid"`

It's needed to substitute @coid with hexadecimal literal. For example, it should be executed like this:

`"SELECT $coid_ref FROM db.$ext WHERE $coid = x'AA23909F'"`

But, when I try to add parameter via command.Parameters.Add("@coid", "AA23909F") driver tries to add it as string, which leads to error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a regular string.

You need to use a hexadecimal literal value.

From what I could find...

```
command.Parameters.Add("@coid", "\xAA\x23\x90\x9F")
```

What DB2 platform are you working with?  If an EBCDIC platform (IBM i or z/OS) you might have a problem with your string being translated...

But this seems to be a really strange need.  Is the column really defined as a 4 byte binary string?  (is so it should look like CHAR(4) FOR BIT DATA assuming you're not using unicode.)

Comment: mustaccio..."\xAA" is a hexadecimal literal.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: a binary literal (though net yet supported will look like this:   0b00000100   per https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status

Comment: There is no reference to "hexadecimal literal" in the link you provided. What you show is a _character literal_ that you supply as a parameter for a binary (`FOR BIT DATA`) column. You are free to use terms invented by you, of course.

Comment: Because .NET doesn't provide a true hexadecimal literal, ie something like x'AA23909F' or 0xAA23909F for an arbitrary size.  .NET only defines hexadecimal literals for fixed sized integers. Not every language has this limitation.  So yeah, I'm calling a .NET character literal made up of only hexadecimal escape sequences a "hexadecimal literal".

Comment: You are also correct that the FOR BIT DATA defines a binary column in the DB (with a CCSID of 65535).  But that just means the DB won't try to translate it or interpret it.  The application is responsible for understanding what is stored in the column.  AFAIK, there's no difference between CHAR(10) FOR BIT DATA, CHAR(10) CCSID 65535 or BINARY(10).